# given the median , find an unknown

Tags: statistics

[image]

The number of you cars that students in a class have is sown in the Table above .

If median is $3$, write down an inequality satisfied by $x$ .

My workings :

Total number of students = $40+x$ students

Median position = $\frac{n+1}{2} = \frac{41+x}{2}$

Total students with $0$ to $3$ toys = $31+ x$ students

I do not understand how to manage this qn . Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The inequality that you are looking for is $x<8$.

For your median to be equal to 3 it should be the case that at least half of the observations are $\geq3$ and less than half of the observations are $\geq4$ (which obviously holds here). So, you need $4+12+x<15+4+5 \Leftrightarrow x<8$.

Just notice that if $x=8$ then the median would be 2.5, which you do not want.